# “The project doesn't know how to run the profile sample.WinUI”

Tags: .net, visual-studio, maui

When I try to build a MUAI project, it gives the error “The project doesn't know how to run the profile sample.WinUI". The project gets built but it doesn't run. I am using Visual Studio 2022 Preview(17.0.0 Preview 1.0) and .NET version 6.0.100-preview.5.21302.13

Comment: This is still an issue for me with VS 2022 preview 3 and .NET 6 preview 6. Note that in VS 2021 the solution was to right click the WinUI project and "Deploy" but this option is not present in 2022.

Comment: This may related to the "Development tools for .NET" component of the Visual Studio installation. See [VS2022 - The project doesn't know how to run the profile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70093156) and [How to fix "The project doesn't know how to run the profile ConsoleREPL" in Visual Studio? - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/655393/how-to-fix-34the-project-doesn39t-know-how-to-run.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Haven't found this documented yet, but it turns out you need to install the 2022 equivalent of `Single-project MSIX Packaging Tools for VS 2019`. You can find the 2022 version here:

[Single-project MSIX Packaging Tools for VS 2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProjectReunion.MicrosoftSingleProjectMSIXPackagingToolsDev17)

Once installed you can build the WinUI project then right-click and select `Deploy`. Debugging and running should then work as expected.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it didn't work for me. I'm trying to debug a windows console application and I'm getting the same exact error message as the op

Comment: @DarthVegan this answer is specific to preview releases of .Net 6 MAUI projects. Seeing this error in other contexts would suggest you don't have the right project selected as the startup project.

Comment: I only have a single project in the solution which of course is the startup