# VS2022 - The project doesn't know how to run the profile

Tags: visual-studio-2022

VS2022 release version - I am getting this on a brand new empty WPF project.
I see posts about VS2022 Preview doing this but not the release version.
Anyone have any ideas ?
[image: Error dialog: The project doesn't know how to run the profile]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get around the error by adding 'Development tools for .NET' component.

[image]

I have created [feedback](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/The-project-doesnt-know-how-to-run-the-/1596305) on this in Visual Studio developer community.

Comment: ... coincidental band aid

Comment: not sure as it works for me too

Comment: This works for me. I'm working on a MonoGame based net6.0 project on an upgraded installation of VS 2022. See also [How to fix "The project doesn't know how to run the profile ConsoleREPL" in Visual Studio? - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/655393/how-to-fix-34the-project-doesn39t-know-how-to-run.html).

Answer (score 0):

For me installing the `Development tools for .NET` component is not working, and I don't want to reinstall the entire VS, so I tried to unselect `.NET desktop development` in VS installer, then reselect it to reinstall these packages, finally VS can run my console .NET6 project.